# Javascript sorting : end of string?

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, indexof

I need to compare some strings in Javascript, and check if a string is at the end or in the middle.

*Example* : If by searching for people named "Depp" I get

```
["Bob Deppo", "Johnny Depp"]
```

then the ordered output should be

```
["Johnny Depp", "Bob Deppo"]
```

Basically I am looking for am way to verify the existence of a substring at the end of another string. Something like :

```
people.sort(function(a,b){

 if(a.indexOf(" Depp"+[ AND NOTHING MORE ])!== -1) return 1;

});
```

A few example would be :

```
"Johnny Depp".indexOf(" Depp"+[ AND NOTHING MORE ] !== -1 ) = TRUE
"Bob Deppsomething".indexOf(" Depp"+[ AND NOTHING MORE ] !== -1 ) = FALSE
```

If this [AND NOTHING MORE] symbol which would signal the end of a string exists, does one for the beginning of a string also exist ?

**Possible Solution (but very nasty)** :

One way of doing it would be to get the index of that substring " Depp" with indexOf (6) and see if added together with the length of the substring "Depp" (5) we get the total length of the string "Johnny Depp" (11)

```
function atEnd(substring, string){
    return (string.indexOf(substring) + substring.length == string.length);
}
```

Not very elegant though.

So does such a [AND NOTHING MORE] symbol exist ?

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript or you can use a regular expression.

Comment: @akonsu Indeed! I should have searched better. Sorry for that.