# Check URL if it has a specific anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a user requests the following address (from another page), I want to scroll down to the contact form area:

```
http://www.example.com/index.html#contact
```

How would I check if the URL contains the hash `#contact`?

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check if one string contains another substring in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: And perhaps even more specific dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/280634/1313143

Comment: Haha you guys above are funny. The two first answers are so beautiful. And no, there is no better question/answer on SO that covers this as succintly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't. The browser does that for you. Simply have a `name="contact"` attribute and the browser will scroll down to that element automatically.
for instance:

```
<h2 name="contact">The contact form is below</h2>
<form> ...
```

Comment: note that this will not work if you require a smooth scroll

Answer (score 4):

You can use this simple code to get the URL hash.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash == "#contact") {
    // code
}
```

Note: this will also return the "#" tag!

Answer (score 1):

`url.match(/#contact$/)` should return the matches as an array. Just check if it's not null.

Answer (score 0):

The hash in the URL will map to the node with the same ID value. So in your case the page will auto scroll to div with an idea of `#contact`

Comment: It's actually name. (id only works in HTML5 because browsers tend to forgive you for this mistake)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
var urlName = document.location.href;
var hash = urlName.split("#").length;
```