# Javascript: How do I prevent reappending a string multiple times

Tags: javascript

I’ve scripted it to append a string to the URL and when I keep issuing the request it keeps appending over and over again

In OnBeforeRequest function

```
if (oSession.uriContains("www.youtube.com/results?search_query=")) {

    var sText = "+test1+test2+test3";

    oSession.fullUrl = oSession.fullUrl + sText;
}
```

visual info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT4bF.png

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to do this would be to see whether the string in question already ends with what you're adding, and if so, don't add it again.

[endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript)

```
if (oSession.uriContains("www.youtube.com/results?search_query=")) 
{
  var str = oSession.fullUrl;
  var sAppend = "+test1+test2+test3";
  if (oSession.fullUrl.indexOf(sAppend, str.length - sAppend.length) < 0)
  {
     oSession.fullUrl = str + sAppend;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry,tried several times, but its not working, or rather it does not even append at all. http://i.imgur.com/JSExReN.jpg

Comment: fixed a typo. try it again.

Comment: Thanks, but there is one new problem, it gets appended to **page result** as well.Because of that, I can only browse the first page. http://imgur.com/GX29THV

Comment: That's a different question, so you technically should mark this one as answered and ask a new question. The change is simple: just change the line to `if (oSession.fullUrl.indexOf(sAppend) < 0)`