# Javascript - How to find specific string using .indexOf instead of just the beginning

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

I'm trying to run some code if a string is found in the users URL. However I only want it to run if there is nothing else following the string. The string appears at the end of the URL like this.

http://shop.com/?searchTerm=bread

My code:

```
if (window.location.search.indexOf('searchTerm=bread') > -1) {
do stuff;
}
```

This works fine but the problem is it will still run if the string is 'searchTerm=bread+rolls' I don't want this to happen. Any ideas?

I should also mention there is a bunch of other parameters in the URL that change, but the one I'm trying to target is always at the end. I'm also unable to use any libraries.

http://shop.com/?p=kjsl&g=sdmjkl&searchTerm=bread

Comment: Use a regular expression, and anchor it to the end with `$`.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: Will your url (searchTerm=bread+rolls) has more string behind e.g. searchTerm=bread+rolls&xxx=xxx?

Comment: `window.location.search == '?searchTerm=bread'` to simple for your taste somehow …?

Comment: @CBroe sorry I didn't mention that there are a bunch of other parameters that preceed the one I'm trying to target and they are always different.

Comment: @Barmar that looks like what I need but I've no idea how to use them, I'll look into it..

Comment: @Zesky no there's no other string after what I'm trying to target but there is many parameters before.

Comment: www.regular-expression.info has a tutorial on regexp. Every programmer should become familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks I'm still a beginner, will check itout.

Comment: _“no there's no other string after what I'm trying to target but there is many parameters before”_ – well then you should be able to test that with a combination of `lastIndexOf` and the string length …

Comment: Duplicate question. Look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript)

Comment: There is no semantic meaning for a query parameter coming in any particular position in the list. You shouldn't be depending on that. Chances are high that something will break in the future if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following example:

```
var url = window.location.search;
if (/searchTerm=bread$/.test(url)) {
    do stuff;
}
else if (/searchTerm=cheese\+slices$/.test(url)) {
    do stuff;
}
```

$ represent end of line.
\ backslash is use to escape the special character like +

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

You want `String.prototype.endsWith`. See [MDN docs](http://ttps://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith). That page also provides a polyfill. For availability, see [caniuse](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#String.prototype.endsWith).

However, in Chrome 41 this native implementation is 25% slower than the fastest alternative, which uses `slice`:

```
function endsWithSlice(string1, string2) {
  return string1.slice(-string2.length) === string2;
}
```

The regexp solution presented in another answer is 50% slower. The MDN polyfill is 38% slower, but still faster than regexp. See [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/string-endswith-vs-regexp).