# Confirm the Ending of an String (Varying Ending Length)

Tags: javascript, string, substring

This task requires that you write a function that takes two arguments. The first argument is a string called `str` and the second argument is a string that our target ending named `target`. The task is to verify that the ending of `str` is identical to the target ending. The instructions indicate to use the `.substr()` method to compare the endings to the targets. The problem I have is that there are going to be multiple starting points and length arguments for the `.substr` method since the target endings can be of variable length. Take a look at my attempt to solve this issue and please direct me in the right path.

```
function end(str, target) {
  var start = str.length - (target.length - 1);
  if(str.substr(start, str.length) == target){
     return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}

end('Bastian', 'n');
```

Comment: Your code should work fine if `var start = str.length - target.length;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [endsWith in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript)

Comment: @torazaburo is not a DUP: the user asked _The instructions indicate to use the .substr() method to compare the endings to the targets_ ... this questios is not about endWidth.

Comment: @oneway Well, it's a matter of how narrowly one interprets the question. The question has a broader context of how to do the equivalent of `endsWith`; it has a narrower context of how to do that in one particular, **suboptimal** way. It's well within the scope of legitimate answers, IMHO, to suggest alternative, better approaches to solve the underlying question. A question **is** a duplicate if it asks the same basic question, especially when, as in this case, the question suggested as a duplicate **does** provide an answer giving a correct implementation based on `substr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**

As @torazaburo said. The correct answer Is:

```
function end(str, target) {
    return target === str.substr(str.length - target.length);
}
```

Because *The string **does** end with a null string*

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

```
function end(str, target) {
    return target.length > 0 && target === str.substr(str.length - target.length);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tqsx0gLa/2/

**From Comments:**
This code is setting up a logical comparison using the `&&` operator. The left side `target.length > 0` should always return `true` with a valid `target` input. The left side is setting target equal to the `substr` starting at the point located by taking the `str.length` (the position at the far right of the `str`) and subtracting the `target` length (to arrive at the start point of our substring). There is no need for an end point input because the substring will run to the end of `str`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It would help for a newcomer to have an explanation so let me take a shot. This code is setting up a logical comparison using the '&&' operator. The left side 'target.length > 0' should always return 'true' with a valid 'target' input. The left side is setting target equal to the 'substr' starting at the point located by taking the 'str.length' (the position at the far right of the 'str') and subtracting the 'target' length (to arrive at the start point of our substring). There is no need for an en point input because the substring will run to the end of the str.

Comment: Why is `target.length > 0` necessary?

Comment: Case 4 should return a true. The string **does** end with a null string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a easy solution :

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {

  var result;

  //getting the last string depend on target length 
  var last = str.substring(str.length - target.length);   

  //checking the last string with the target
  if(last === target){ 

     result = true;

  } else {

   result = false;
  }

return result;
}
```

Comment: Using an if to store a boolean in a variable declared in the header - is there a more convoluted way to write `return last === target`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function end(str, target) {
  var start = str.length - target.length;

  if(str.substr(start) == target){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You can also try this code.

Comment: Why would you not write `return str.substr(start) == target;`?

Comment: Cool. It's more explicit I guess. But yours is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The substring method can take a negative value to work from the end of the string. The solution to your problem is very simple:

```
function end (str, target) {
  return str.substr(-target.length) === target;
}

end("simple is better", "better"); // returns true

// which is the same as writing
"simple is better".substr(-6) === "better" // true again
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
const solution = (str, target) => str.endsWith(target);
```

The cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let ending = str.slice(str.length-target.length)
  return ending == target
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Congratulation", "on"))
```