# What type of variable is this in php: {{%= description %}}

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I'm modifying a wordpress plugin (Page Builder by SiteOrigin 2.0.7) and there are some variables throughout one of the php files (tpl/js-templates.php) in a notation that I don't recognize. The variables look like this: `{{%= foo %}}` and they always appear in the midst of html.

Here is an example of some of the html:

```
<div class="so-buttons">
    {{%= buttons %}}
</div>
<div class="so-content panel-dialog">
    <img src="{{%= url %}}">
    {{%= content %}}
</div>
```

What is this? Is this blade template notation?

How can I use this variable in a conditional? For instance, I'd like to test if `{{%= url %}}` is a jpg url.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure but it looks like Handlebars it's basically a javascript library look it up it might be that

Comment: Which plugin and which version? Please supply all the details that you have.

Comment: I've just added that info. It's [Page Builder](https://siteorigin.com/page-builder/) by SiteOrigin 2.0.7 and the file is tpl/js-templates.php.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit new to me, so I may be wrong here, but lets follow the code backwards through the plugin..

`{{%` appears in `tpl\js-templates.php` 36 times and `js\siteorigin-panels.js` (and the .min version) once. `%}}` appears only 34 times in the same php file, still once in the js file.

In the .js file they appear at line 14+, here:

```
String.prototype.panelsProcessTemplate = function(){
    var s = this;
    s = s.replace(/{{%/g, '<%');
    s = s.replace(/%}}/g, '%>');
    s = s.trim();
    return s;
};
```

So they're using `{{%` as a placeholder and using JS to replace it with `<%`. The same is happening with the closing `%}}` (now `%>`).

It also shows up as a sort of shorthand for `<script>`?

```
{{% if( count > 1 ) { %}} <span class="count">({{%= count %}})</span>{{% } %}
```

Taking a look at the top of this file for any comments on what it does, we see `Convert template into something compatible with Underscore.js templates` so we know we should pull up the [`Underscore.js` documentation](http://devdocs.io/underscore/) for future reference.

Well, how is `panelsProcessTemplate()` string prototype used? Several times in the mentioned js file, e.g. at line 211:

```
panels.view.widget = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template( $('#siteorigin-panels-builder-widget').html().panelsProcessTemplate() )
```

This is inside of an extension of `Backbone.View`, so the [Backbone documentation](http://devdocs.io/backbone/) may also be good to open up..

First, let's look at what our function is directly processing - `#siteorigin-panels-builder-widget` is in the php file at line 93+:

```
<script type="text/template" id="siteorigin-panels-builder-widget">
<div class="so-widget ui-draggable">
<div class="so-widget-wrapper">
    <div class="title">
        <h4>{{%= title %}}</h4>
        <span class="actions">
            <a href="#" class="widget-edit"><?php _e('Edit', 'siteorigin-panels') ?></a>
            <a href="#" class="widget-duplicate"><?php _e('Duplicate', 'siteorigin-panels') ?></a>
            <a href="#" class="widget-delete"><?php _e('Delete', 'siteorigin-panels') ?></a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <small class="description">{{%= description %}}</small>
</div>
</div>
</script>
```

[`text/template` is a browser-ignored template client-side code can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4912608/1265817). So it's replacing `{{%` with `<%` and `%}}` with `%>` in this template, running it through the `template()` function, and setting it all to the `template` variable in this view.

What is `template()` doing? It's not defined in this file, but it is in the [Underscore.js documentation under the template section](http://devdocs.io/underscore/#template). Apparently it's actually the whole `_.template()`, not just `template()`. Here's the overview:

> Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering. Useful for rendering complicated bits of HTML from JSON data sources. Template functions can both interpolate values, using <%= … %>, as well as execute arbitrary JavaScript code, with <% … %>. [...]

So, we know right now that Underscore.js is using `<%` and `%>` as their data identifiers in templates, both for variables and arbitrary JavaScript as we saw above.

**We know what `{{% .. %}}` is**

`{{%= description %}}` in this case is more-or-less saying `<script> document.write(description); </script>`. It's outputting the `description` parameter into the template HTML.

If I were a betting man, I'd bet you can change the widget title and description through the WordPress/ Page Builder Admin.

As for checking what the variable is, you'll likely be best suited checking after everything is rendered on the page.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   if ($("#id .so-content img").prop("src").endsWith(".jpg")) {
     ...
```

`endsWith` being a [custom String prototype defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548133/1265817).

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, these expressions are part of the [Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/) programming language. Please see the attached link for a full description.