# What is the !== operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators

As the question says, what exactly is the function of the !== operator? (*Exclaimation, Equals, Equals*).

Yes there are two equal signs. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548133/4546874).

> ```
> function endsWith(str, suffix) { 
>     return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;  
> }
> ```

Is it a typo? I doubt it. It is an old post and with so many upvotes, it should surely have been corrected one day or the other.

Or is it a valid operator? If so, what does it do?

Comment: [MDN - Non-identity / strict inequality (!==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Non-identity_strict_inequality_(!))

Comment: There are many questions on this topic which can be found on this site. I recommend reading [this](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types.equality) about comparisons.

Comment: [ES2015 - 7.2.13 Strict Equality Comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison)

Comment: Ok, I understand it's a duplicate. But I could not find it even by googling. And it's only a partial duplicate.

Comment: And if i don't know about `!==`, how in the world am I expected to search for `===`? Usually I would delete duplicates but not this one. I don't think at all that this question should have been closed.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ no one blames you - it's tricky to find about operators in the google (but now you know that it's easy to do in the standard)

Comment: @zerkms Nor do I think anyone blames me. It's just that duplicate flags dishearten me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *strict inequality*: `a !== b` iff type(`a`) ≠ type(`b`) or `a` ≠ `b`.

Since *strict equality* (`===`) is defined as:

- `a === b` iff type(`a`) = type(`b`) ∧ `a` = `b`,

Strict *inequality* is its negation, so:

- `!(a === b)`
- ≡ `!`(type(`a`) = type(`b`) ∧ `a` = `b`)
- ≡ (type(`a`) ≠ type(`b`) ∨ `a` ≠ `b`).

**References.** The semantics of the comparison are in [#strict-equality-comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) of the ES6 spec.

**Ack.** Thanks to [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) for the correction: types are evaluated first. That's important because if the types fail to match, the inequality won't even be checked. Also thanks to him for pointing me to the right place in the spec for the semantics of the relation.

Comment: Btw, type is compared first.

Comment: @zerkms Nice! I glanced over the [semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-equality-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), but didn't catch that.

Comment: it's here http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison

Comment: @zerkms Ah! I appreciate that. I was reading the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

Valid. It's basically doing strict non equality comparison. Checking to see if the type is not equal as well as the value.