# Error "Object has no method 'endsWith'" on custom grunt task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I ran into an error in a custom grunt task. Below I posted a simple test case relating the problem :

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function( grunt ){

    grunt.task.registerTask( 'endsWith', 'Test of string.prototype.endsWith', function(){
        var value = grunt.option('value');
        grunt.log.writeln( typeof value );
        grunt.log.writeln( value.endsWith( 'bar' ) );
    })

};
```

**Test**

```
> grunt endsWith --value=foobar
Running "endsWith" task
string
Warning: Object foobar has no method 'endsWith' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Execution Time (2016-02-12 16:15:19 UTC)
Total 12ms
```

It's like grunt doesn't recognize the String.proptotype.endsWith function. Is that normal ?

Edit: I'm using node v0.10.4

Comment: What version of `node` are you running? (Run `node -v` to find out)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.endsWith` is an ES6 feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) and wasn't implemented in Node.js v0.10.4.

To use `.endsWith` either upgrade Node.js or [add in a polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript):

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function(suffix) {
    return this.indexOf(suffix, this.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on older version of node you can use String.match method.

replace

```
grunt.log.writeln(value.endsWith('bar'));
```

with

```
grunt.log.writeln( value.match("bar$") );
```

complete code

```
module.exports = function( grunt ){

    grunt.task.registerTask( 'endsWith', 'Test of string.prototype.endsWith', function(){
        var value = grunt.option('value');
        grunt.log.writeln( typeof value );
        grunt.log.writeln( value.match("bar$") );
    })

};
```