# Java. Check if the last two characters are equal to '-1'

Tags: java

I have to write the condition in Java, which will check whether the variable ends with the characters '-1'. If so let assign another variable value of '1', if not '2'.

I do not know Java, but I wrote something like this...

```
var adres = 'something@something.com-1';

if ( adres.contains("-1") ) {
  { var someVariable = '1' };
} else {
  { var someVariable = '2' };
}
```

The script does not work. In addition, the "contains" is not the best solution, because the address might look like this: 'something@something.com-12'.

I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: This looks like JavaScript which is _not_ Java.

Comment: @DeveloperXY wrong duplicate, this looks very much like javascript.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider The OP said : **"I have to write the condition in Java"** so, he obviously targets, Java.

Comment: Well, in case the OP changes it I suggest to close it as a duplicate for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

```
if(adres.substring( adres.length() - 2, adres.length() ).equals( "-1" ) )
```

in Java (you choose java as tag ^^)

Comment: 1. format your code properly. 2. why would someone use substring + equals if he could just use `endsWith(...)`?

Comment: cause i didnt know that there is endsWith(), i just told him ONE way to do it, the ONE that i know, but thanks for telling