# is it possible check whether `10.0` is float or int in javascript ??

Tags: javascript

I am scratching my head to find numbers like `10.0` , `1.0` are whether integers or floats. is there any way to check whether `10.0` is float or int in javascript ?? 
Thanks

Comment: to answer your question, `'10.0'` is as number `10` and that is an integer value. you have to use string operations/regular expressions to check the **string** if you need to know zeroes after the dot.

Comment: @Quentin and other mods, I nominated for reopening because technically this isn't a duplicate . This is specifically asking for checking for `.0` in JS floats

Comment: @Oscar — They aren't strings, they are number literals. `10.0 === 10`

Comment: @Quentin correct, which is something we understand by OP didn't. 10.0 _is_ 10 which I mentioned in my answer. The question you marked it as a dupe with however is asking to check for any floats where is this asking specifically how to handle this. I mentioned it needs to be a string to do this.

Comment: @Quentin yes, i am specifically asking numbers ends with `.0` , i am not asking about if variable is int or float

Comment: @REDDYPRASAD — You can't distinguish between `10` and `10.0`. As I said, they are the same

Comment: @OscarGodson, I don't see any reason to reopen the question. But you may ask quentin to change the duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/280634). But as the question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) I would prefer I leave it as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can check by dividing by 1

```
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

To expand a bit more as well, you can't ever have `10.0`in JavaScript. If you have `var i = 10.0` and you log out `i` it will return `10`. This is common across most (all?) programming languages.

If you really need to keep the `.0` you need to store it as a string. You then can simply check the string for a `.` like `'10.0'.indexOf('.') > -1`

Comment: ```1.0 % 1 === 0``` returns `true` . but `1.0` is not integer. Its float

Comment: why not check the number against it's integer value, like `n === Math.floor(n)`?

Comment: @REDDYPRASAD added more to my answer. `1.0` doesn't actually exist in JS really.

Comment: @NinaScholz it won't work. ```Math.floor(1.0) === 1.0``` returns `true`

Comment: as i wrote above under the question, a *number* with a dot and following zeroes is for javascript a number - and while javascript does not know integers, you couzld just check if you have an integer number. javascript uses for *all* number 64 bit floats. the only way, to check is to take a string and perform a check for dot and zeroes.

Comment: Common across all languages? Strongly typed languages make very clear distinctions, not only between integers and floats, but between different subtypes (short signed integer, short unsigned integer, long integer...). But course JavaScript is loosely typed and it only has `Number` as numeric type. Thus it isn't entirely clear of what the question is really asking.

Comment: in some languages, `10.0` denotes a float, but not in javascipt, bacause all numbers are floats.