# jQuery select attribute with a matched string

Tags: jquery

Many anchor tags on my website have Windows ".exe" file link in its href attribute.

If that anchor tag is clicked on Mobile or Mac OS, I want to popup a message: "Sorry only available on Windows".

Any anchor tag whose href ends with ".exe" matches the condition. How can I select such anchor tags in jQuery?

For example:

`<a href="http://www.example.com/downloads/abc.exe"></a>`

should be selected by jQuery because it ends with ".exe"

But

`<a href="http://www.example.com/downloads/abc.jpg"></a>`

should **"NOT"** be selected by jQuery because it does not end with ".exe" in it.

I have the following code:

```
if (/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
{
 jQuery("a[href*='.exe']").attr("href","#popmake-1117");
}
```

But it detects .exe anywhere in the href, and not in the end. Also, it works only on mobiles and not on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: While the `.filter()` works out for more complex conditions, there is a valid [CSS modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) (`[attribute$="value"]`) for *ends with*:

```js
if (/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  jQuery("a[href$='.exe']").attr("href","#popmake-1117");
}
```

---

**Initial answer**

This is how I'd do it, using `.filter()`:

```js
let exes = $('a[href]').filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr('href').indexOf('.exe') > -1
});

// let's test it

exes.css({
  border: '1px solid red'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#something.exe">has exe</a>
<a href="#something">no exe</a>
```

To check if `.exe` is ending the string, you can use `substring`:

```js
let exes = $('a[href]').filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr('href').substr($(this).attr('href').length - 4) === '.exe'
});

// let's test it

exes.css({
  border: '1px solid red'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#something.exe">has exe</a>
<a href="#something">no exe</a>
<a href="#something.exellent">exe not at the end of it</a>
```

Comment: Can I check if href specifically ends with ".exe" ? and not anywhere in it?

Comment: @Comp yes, you can do `return $(this).attr('href').substr($(this).attr('href').length - 4) === '.exe'`

Comment: @Comp, updated answer with another method, which appears to be what you should use. There's a valid CSS modified for *"ends with"*. `$('a[href$=".exe"]')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf()` to check if it contains specify string

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
  $("a").on("click",function(){
     var href = $(this).attr("href");
     if(href.indexOf("example.com/downloads") > -1 && href.indexOf(".exe")> - 1){
       alert("Can download");
     }else{
       alert("Sorry only available on Windows");
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.example.com/downloads/abc.exe">Download exe</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/downloads/abc.apk">Download apk</a>
```

Comment: Can I check if href specifically ends with ".exe" ? and not anywhere in it?

Comment: @ComputerUser so you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript

Comment: yes you can check if index of '.exe' is equal length of href minus length of '.exe' which is 4. i edited my answer, accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

look for index of two values.

```
var link=$('a').attr('href'); 
if(link.indexOf('example.com/downloads')>-1 && 
 link.indexOf('.exe')==link.length-4){
//do something
 }
```

Comment: Can I check if href specifically ends with ".exe" ? and not anywhere in it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of navigator.platform and indexOf

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    if (href.indexOf(".exe") > -1) {
      console.log(navigator.platform);

      if (navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") > -1) {
        alert("You're using windows!");
        //proceed

      } else {
        alert("Only available in Windows!");
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.test/test.exe">Test.exe</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
```