# Remove all items from an array that don't end in X

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. It looks something like this:

```
[
    { name: "item1", moreDataHere },
    { name: "item2X", moreDataHere },
    { name: "item3", moreDataHere }
]
```

I want to remove all items that DON'T end in X. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this

```
[
    { name: "item1",  },
    { name: "item2X",  },
    { name: "item3",  }
].filter(x=>x.name.endsWith('X'))
```

Comment: Probably add a `!`