# Check the end of string (regular expression)

Tags: javascript

i am trying to heck if a string (first argument, str) ends with the given target string (second argument, target).  `function confirmEnding(str, target) {   return  /target$/.test(str) }`
Test string`confirmEnding("Bastian","n")` show false. What i am doing wrong? Can i use regular expression as argument of function?
;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [endsWith in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280634/endswith-in-javascript) Also relevant: [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2):

If it's always a string, then you can just use `String#endsWith`

```js
function checkEnd(str, target) {
  return str.endsWith(target);
}

console.log(checkEnd("Bastion", "n"));
```

If you want to cast `target` into a regex, but note that this won't escape out any of the special characters in `target`. i.e. `checkEnd('special)',')')` will fail due to the regex being invalid:

```js
function checkEnd(str, target) {
  return new RegExp(`${target}$`).test(str);
}

console.log(checkEnd("Bastion", "n"));
```